# Transaction in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-mvc

I am using **spring boot** in my application.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class PushMysqlTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunQuery.class);
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(PushMysqlTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        startTransaction();
    }


    public void startTransaction() throws InterruptedException {
        LOGGER.info("=========== Transaction started ===========");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("start transaction");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("select * from push_multithread where status = 1 for update");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("update push_multithread set status = 30 where id=1");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("commit");
        LOGGER.info("========= Transaction ending ===========");
    }


}
```

What the above code does is, it starts transaction, update a table and commit using `JDBCTemplate`.

Is their any better way to achieve above transation in spring boot using anootations or JPA etc?

Comment: I use Hibernate, so not sure my ideas will help you. I use  CrudRepository interface for database requests. After that I create Service annotated bean. This bean contains Transactional methods So if I want to call request I call a Transactional method and it should call Repository method.

Comment: could you please update your answer with code

Comment: No I cannot. This is because I would have to write an article about this, though I not feel like can teach here, sorry. Though you can find the solution samples with search engines.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use google for this? You have multiple way to do this :P

For example: `@Transactional` annotation on method.

Or using XML file to wrap methods with transaction.

Just look for this on google: https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

Comment: I think using @Transactional is better approach

Comment: based on your suggestion I am now using 

`@Transactional
 public void startTransaction() throws InterruptedException {
  LOGGER.info("=========== Transaction started ===========");
  jdbcTemplate.execute("select * from push_multithread where status = 1 for update");
  
  jdbcTemplate.execute("update push_multithread set status = 100 where id=1");
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  LOGGER.info("========= Transaction ending ===========");
 }`

Comment: could you please add these lines to your answer so that I can accept your answer, this will help readers in future, as they will get modified code

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spring data CrudRepository which does a lot of things for you out of the box. Just create an interface and "map" it to the object you want to persist in the database, by writing the class and the type the ID field of your entity in between <>, like so:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyOjbect, Long> {

MyObject someDBQuery(String param)

}
```

then in your service, autowired it and call your method, like so:

```
public class myService {

@Autowired
MyRepository myRepository;

@Transactional
public MyObject doSomething(String param) {

// call the repository
MyObject myObject = myRepository.someDBQuery(param);

}
}
```

Now before that, pleeease make sure you know what @Transactional is used for and WHY would you use it. More info [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional).
 Also see all the power CrudRepository has, because it has a lot to offer. More info - [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

Before all this, import the spring-data-jpa library into your project.
Good luck